# Power apps. Retrieve values of record with multiple choices in SharePoint list column for a dropdown box

Tags: powerapps-canvas, modelmultiplechoicefield

For reference I have recreated this app https://www.matthewdevaney.com/make-a-power-apps-approvals-form/
I changed the equipment column to have multiple values and now some code dosent work because the entry is not a record anymore. I think it is a table now.

I have some code for e.g here;

```
ViewForm(frm_Request);
Set(varRequest, frm_Request.LastSubmit);

If(varRequest.Status.Value="Submitted",
    Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
        varRequest.Manager.Email,
        "IT Equipment Request - Approval Required",
        "An I/T equipment request was made for a "&varRequest.Equipment.Value&" by "&varRequest.Employee.DisplayName&".  <a href="""&varAppID&"?recordid="&varRequest.ID&""">Click here</a> to approve/reject the request."
    )
)
```

at &varRequest.Equipment.Value& (.Value) has an error "expecting record value"

I tried changing this to concat(varRequest.equipment, Value & ",") But it seems to create errors when running the app

Is there a work around for this ?

Im very new to coding and power apps in general so sorry if this is missing any details.

[Image of error when running the app after adding concat()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtQQC.jpg)